# Yii imagePuzzle extension

Tags: php, yii

I tried to add imagepuzzle extension to my website. I added but there is a problem. Image does not divide right in columns and rows. I give it 3 cols and 4 rows. But picture divide in to rows.

```php
$this->widget('application.extensions.imagepuzzle.Puzzle', array(
    'columns'=>3,
    'rows'=>4,
    'images'=>array(
        'image1.jpg',
        'image2.jpg',
        'image3.jpg',
        'image4.jpg',
        'image5.jpg',
        'image6.jpg',
        'image7.jpg',
        'image8.jpg',
        'image9.jpg'
    )
));
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: add code to your post (click edit), that will help us trying to help you...

Comment: <?php 
$this->widget('application.extensions.imagepuzzle.Puzzle', 
array('columns'=>3, //columns
'rows'=>4, // rows 
'images'=>array('image1.jpg',
'image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg',
'image5.jpg','image6.jpg','image7.jpg',
'image8.jpg','image9.jpg') //images shown in the game
)); ?>

Comment: if you added the extension into the `application/protected/extension/` folder and your images into `imagepuzzle/assets/images/` then this should work... you'll find more info on the extension documentation page: [http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/imgpuzzle/](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/imgpuzzle/)

Comment: I did all of you said. But its result the same. What may it be a problem?

Comment: not sure, you might get an answer faster on the yii forum though...